# increase webrtc frame rate to allow virtual desktop view

Tags: webrtc, aframe, oculus

Is it possible to increase the web RTC frame rate during screen sharing to allow useable viewing of a virtual desktop in VR? Current testing, with the request set for 30, shows the frame rate at about 20 fps for a desktop-to desktop connection, 17 in a-frame, and 13 when connecting to Oculus Quest 2. At those speeds, the mouse, controlled by the source computer, lags behind its actual position in the shared screen view just enough to make it very difficult to use. Here is the current code to try and set the frame rate:

---

var displayMediaOptions = {
video: {
frameRate: 30
}
};

window.displayMediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);

---

I also tried minFrameRate and increasing the bit rate in the peer connection, per other posts, to no effect. Most of the posts discuss how to *reduce* the bit rate, and some, for example https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server/wiki/How-to-improve-WebRTC-bit-rate%3F recommend 10-20 as the optimal frame rate, but can it be forced higher if necessary without breaking everything, or is another solution needed?  Other virtual desktop solutions require a native app and/or cable link to the source computer - is that the solution?

Comment: This works OK with Chrome as the shared screen source, up to about frameRate: 60, with the results showing just less than that, adequate for now for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC implements congestion control: it dynamically probes the network, and determines a rate that is safe to use.  If the probed rate is too low, it will reduce the frame rate, reduce the resolution, or reduce the video quality.

Short of using a faster network, there are three ways to increse framerate at the cost of resolution or quality:

- you may decrese the capture resolution by passing the `video.height` and `video.width` constraints to `getUserMedia`;
- you may request that the video be downsampled, by passing the `scaleResolutionDownBy` constraint to `RTCRtpSender.setParameters`;
- you may request that the rate control prefer to sacrifice resolution and quality by passing a `contentHint` to `RTCRtpSender.setParameters`.